# Alternative to Conditional Compilation in C# for Database Initialisation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly

I'm investigating an alternative implementation for database initialisation that doesn't rely upon #if #elif..... (doens't work for .Net code in VS2017 known issue) to select customer specific database initialisers. One approach which seems sensible for both development and CI/CD environments is the following:

- Create a database initialiser interface.
- Create a c# assembly project for each site that contains an instance of the 
  above interface.
- Configure the database layer of the solution to load the database initialiser 
  assembly at runtime.
- Write a powershell script with string parameter 'siteName', builds 
  the solution (based on siteName parameter) renames the site specific database 
  initialiser so that the above step can load the assembly at runtime.

I'm interested to gauge peoples option of this approach to me it seems a scalable solution to the problem, my only concern is loading the assembly at runtime but I guess strong naming and code signing the assembly will mitigate the risk.

This is the type of DI init I want to change remove dependency on #if....

```
private void DatabaseInitialiseDefinitions(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
        #if site1
                    builder.RegisterType<site1ResourceIdentityDefinitions>()
                        .As<IResourceIdentityDefinition>()
                        .SingleInstance();
                    builder.RegisterType<site1UserDefinitions>()
                        .As<IUserDefinitions>()
                    .SingleInstance();
        #elif site2
                    builder.RegisterType<site2ResourceIdentityDefinition>()
                        .As<IResourceIdentityDefinition>()
                        .SingleInstance();
                    builder.RegisterType<site2UserDefinitions>()
                        .As<IUserDefinitions>()
                        .SingleInstance();
        #elif site3
                    builder.RegisterType<site3ResourceIdentityDefinition>()
                        .As<IResourceIdentityDefinition>()
                        .SingleInstance();
                    builder.RegisterType<site3UserDefinitions>()
                        .As<IUserDefinitions>()
                        .SingleInstance();
}
```

Comment: What about *Code Contracts*?

Comment: Is this to provide an IDbConnectionFactory for EF connection string? Or is the database different on schema level,

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "doens't work for .Net code in VS2017 known issue"? Conditional compilation still works fine in my experience... although I'm not sure it would be a good solution here anyway.

Comment: If it is really necessary to create different code for each customer, you could use a framework like [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/mef/). (This should also work in .NET Core.)

Comment: @JonSkeet this is problem I encounter https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2733

Comment: @Rahul Code contracts concerns more how a method should be called and with what parameter values. The problem I'm trying to address is more an architectural one but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @GraemeMiller No it's to enable database seeding with site specific data the schema is the same for all sites.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen that (despite regularly switching project configurations and seeing the IDE change) - and it's important to note that it's just around what gets displayed in the IDE. It's not like conditional compilation genuinely *doesn't work*.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've found conditional compilation doesn't work so for me it's more than just IDE.

Comment: That suggests it's not the same problem that you've linked to then. I use it every day - it really does work fine. I suggest you ask a separate question with a [mcve] about that. I would say that this question is a bit unclear at the moment - and somewhat opinion-based too. I suspect you're unlikely to get much traction with it.

Comment: @Rob The solutions sounds like total overkill for seeding data. We have an entire app built for multi-tenancy and we don't do any compilation level changes per customer. It is all handled at runtime - and each customer gets custom implementations and they can all run on one server. I'd have thought some of per customer service injected via DI or something?

Comment: @GraemeMiller I'm all for a DI based solution how have you configured your DI to select the site specific instance? Do you use a config file? I'm using autofact and the #if was setting the DI.

Comment: Thanks for the advice had a play around and I think I have DI solution that will do the job.

Comment: @Rob great.  Put in answer with my thoughts on how I'd do it. Really depends on the scenario. As ypu are using Autofac already should be pretty straightforward to avoid use of compilation level changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was just one place that you need to do this - then [factory pattern](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/01/11/the-factory-pattern-in-dot-net.aspx) (see the example of replacing compiler directives) to return tenant implementation or something similar is an option.

If it is more tenant-specific versions doing it with DI directly is a lot simpler than build time. Even if you just optionally register additional tenant implementations a DI container like Autofac will pull out the last matching registration unless you ask for an IEnumerable of services. If it was me I would use Dependency Injection and treat the app as multi-tenant. It may be that each app runs in isolation but the code is still multi-tenant.

If you had lots of registrations I'd use child containers to hold registrations that are specific to each tenant.

If you used Autofac then this extension would work - https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant or https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Multitenant (if not .Net Core)

We have used it with multiple strategies to identify the tenant - simplest was simply a configuration setting in app.config that told it which tenant it was running as. The current one is based on hostname so all tenants run under one app. If it was a local application I'd expect a setting in a config that told it which tenant to be.